# need help for a simple code in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write this code, but I don't know how!

This is my code

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char mych, mych2;
    cout<< "Enter a letter:"<< "\n";
    cin>> mych;
    if(mych<=90 && mych>=65)
    {
      cout<<mych2 = mych+32;
    }
    else
    {
      mych2=mych-32;
      cout<< ;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

It shows ascii of 'mych2', But I want it to show capital letter if the entered one is small, and small letter if the entered one is capital.

Comment: Even simple code can benefit from using a debugger. I strongly suggest that you learn how to do that before you write any more code:)

Comment: It's a homework that I need to do, but I have problem with characters and ascii code

Comment: 65 and 90 should at least be replaced with the characters they represent. You're also ignoring the `<cctype>` header, which has a bunch of handy character functions so you don't have to do things like add 32.

Comment: The first thing I would recommend you is to drop the numbers (the numbers Mason, what do they mean) and replace them with char symbols instead (`a`, `z` or `A`). Even the 32 value can be calculated as `A` - `a`. The next logical point is to move the lower/upper character checking into functions which return bool.

Comment: @chris i think for starters they should use inbulilt functions as infrequently as possible.

Comment: @wrangler, I agree with [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) on this one. Rather than scare beginners off with nitty, gritty, ugly details, let them make some cool stuff and problem solve on a higher level that is actually useful in the real world, where you use libraries and weave everything together. When they come out of that course, they have the tools to get a good start on building what they want to build instead of menial programs that have been done a thousand times before. You can always learn a lower level later when you actually need it.

Comment: @chris agree to most of the part but these are the basics and if ignored may confuse user when facing similar questions and after you have understood the concept behind these functions we can use them as many times as we want. And these concepts are of real use when solving higher level programs.

Comment: There is far too much 'How can I get the 1st char of my string, which library functions do I use?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toupper` and `tolower` form [cctype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) to convert upper case to lower case and lower case to upper case.

```
if(isupper(mych)){        //isupper() is used to check if mych is upper case, member of cctype header
    mych2 = tolower(mych);
    cout<<mych2<<endl;
}
else if(islower(mych)){  //islower() is used to check if mych is lower case, member of cctype header
    mych2 = toupper(mych);
    cout<<mych2<<endl;
}
```

To use those function you must include `cctype`

```
#include<cctype>
```

Other way you can compare and convert yourself like

```
if(mych>='A' && mych<='Z')
{
    mych2 = mych-'A'+'a';
    cout<<mych2;
}
else if(mych>='a'&&mych<='z')
{
    mych2=mych-'a'+'A';
    cout<<mych2;
}
```

And if you want to manipulate with raw [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code then

```
if(mych<=90 && mych>=65)
{
    mych2 = mych+32;
    cout<<mych2<<endl;
}
else if(mych<=122&&mych>=97)
{
    mych2=mych-32;
    cout<< mych2;
}
```